# Nested Classes, Inner Class

Tags: java, class, constructor, call

I created an object **d**, right after the constructor, then another object, **f**, in the main method. I need to understand why is `Output` giving an exception (`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`). However, if I don't create the object **d** after the constructor, the program runs with success.

```
public class OuterTwo {
   public OuterTwo() {
       System.out.println("OUTER!");
   }

   OuterTwo d = new OuterTwo();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       OuterTwo f = new OuterTwo();           
   }
}
```

Comment: I will also be grateful for a source to a well written and explained tutorial about nested classes in JAVA.

Comment: I don't see any nested class here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your class is defined as having this field,

```
OuterTwo d = new OuterTwo();
```

Which is equivalent to

```
OuterTwo d;
public OuterTwo() {
  d = new OuterTwo(); // <-- this is infinite recursion.
  System.out.println("OUTER!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent to

```
public class OuterTwo {
        public OuterTwo() {
            d =new OuterTwo();
            System.out.println("OUTER!");   
        }
      OuterTwo d;
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            OuterTwo f = new OuterTwo();           
      }
    }
```

which is leading an infinite recursion.

Comment: This is an infinite _recursion_.

Answer (score 1):

You have done a small mistake here. Use something like this.

```
public class OuterTwo {

     OuterTwo d;

     public OuterTwo() {
          d =new OuterTwo();
          System.out.println("OUTER!");
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          OuterTwo f = new OuterTwo();           
     }
}
```

For better understanding of `Inner` and `Nested` classes follow these links.

[Inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)
and [Nested class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 0):

You experience stack overflow. and that is understandable.
Your OuterTwo class instantiate a member of type OuterTwo.
you have an infinite constructor calls to create OuterTwo objects that holds a reference to an OuterTwo object, on and on..all over again.